# Django creating aliased query outputs

Tags: django, python-3.x

In another question, I was working with a query that gave this output:

```
[{ 'type': 'O', 'count': 54},{ 'type': 'E', 'count': 125},{ 'type': 'C', 'count': 2}]
```

One of the respondents asked why I didn't shortcut it like this:

```
{ 'O': 54, 'E': 125...}
```

While the original question was nicely answered by a pure genius, The thought of this persons input is still in my mind.

How do I "ALIAS" a field in a query such as:

```
Models.Subscription.objects.values("Subscription_Type").annotate(c=Count("Subscription_Type"))
```

to look like what the genius was recommending?  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transform the data in python like this:

```
result=[{ 'type': 'O', 'count': 54},{ 'type': 'E', 'count': 125},{ 'type': 'C', 'count': 2}]

result_as_dict=dict([(type_and_count['type'], type_and_count['count']) for type_and_count in result])

print(result_as_dict)
```

Maybe there is a solution to do this in the django ORM. But I don't know it.

Comment: that's ok.  I'll take it.  Thanks much.